# Label (value of the key) does not show up on the chart in Stackdriver when VMs are grouped by this label

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I am trying to create a chart for CPU usage of all my VMs grouping them by the "pool id" where "pool id" is just a label that I created for each VM. While the time series look perfectly fine, in the legend of the chart the names for the different plots are the same : "usage_time", so there is no way to know which line corresponds to which pool. It seems that the problem occurs only when I group VMs by the custom labels. When I tried to group them by regular criteria such as Zone, I get beautiful distinct names ("usage_time us-central1-c", for example).
Note that I do this via UI. 
Please help.

Thank you,
Alexandra

Comment: Edit the chart, change aggregation to "none" Let me know if this resolves your issue. If not, can you be more specific using exact field names & charts you've configured? From my interpretation of your question, I've made a new chart in my dashboard, resource type cpu_usage, filter by label name (key), grouped by label (value), aggregation "none".

Comment: My case is a little different. I create a chart, set:
metric: CPU_usage
group by: pool_id
Aggregation: mean.
I can not change aggregation to none because  the whole point is to split VMs into pools and displaying their average rather than showing each VM separately.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your issue & was able to reproduce it. The machines are technically grouped by their labels as we both do see multiple lines in the graph equal to the number of label value groups, however the lines are all labeled as "cpu_usage" instead of their label value which they are being grouped by.

This seems to be working as intended, but it is a sub-optimal design. It should be improved to display the label values instead of "cpu_usage". What you are requesting does not seem possible at the moment in Stackdriver Monitoring.

I recommend submitting a public issue or finding an existing issue on Google's [public issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/). This will bring the issue to the attention of Google. The more attention an issue gets, the more likely a change will be implemented so it is important to see if someone else has already created a similar issue.